# Would a cellular-automata universe allow singularities to exist?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, singularities, cellular-automaton

It is usually assumed (almost always) that cosmological singularities (like black hole singularities) are impossible and do not exist in the universe.

If the universe was like a cellular automata (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton), could it produce the right conditions to make these singularities actually exist in that universe?

Comment: Isn't true that singularities are thought no to exist? And that a theory should be develop to remove them? I mean the singularties likely do not exist not the objects/phenomena leading, at the state of the art, to them. @StudyStudy

Comment: @StudyStudy I think you are confusing black holes and singularities

Comment: @StudyStudy when papers are working or talking about singularities is to offer solutions to delete them. Singularities are always avoided or ignored. That is why I was looking for a model that would allow them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on-topic (under the 'mainstream physics') clause.  But cellular automata are discrete, so no kind of singularity which depends on continuity, differentiability or failures of either could exist in such a model.  The singularities in GR are generally of this nature.

Comment: My apologies, I am out of my depth...+1 to see if anybody else can help...I will delete  my comments

Comment: @tfb Generally they are discrete but I found some papers that have propose continuous ceular automata sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924424709003756. Would "continuous-like" singularities exist in a universe based on these cellular automata (like GR black hole singularities)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any cellular automata system in which the automata were continuous in spacetime and had continuous values is simply a way of describing some system of differential equations.  As such, yes, it could have singularities, since GR does.  But that's kind of uninteresting.

Comment: @tfb So a continuous cellular automata would produce/represent a continuous-like universe? Also, while GR does have singularities, they are usually avoided/ignored or thought to not exist. My real question here is: Could such cellular automata (CA) really produce these singularities? Could they reproduce singularities that are thought to be impossible/to not exist (like those present in GR)? Could these singularities that are considered impossible in other theories (for example those in GR) be actually possible/actually exist in such CA? Do you know of any specific CA that could do it?

Comment: @tfb and if yes, Wouldn't that be a problem since singularities are uncomputable? Could these CA-universes allow uncomputable things to exist in them? Also, we can't predict/know what happens in a singularity (for example we can't know if truly all laws/rules would stop existing. It could be the case that instead of not having any laws or rules inside these singularities, GR would stop working in them and a different set of laws and rules would govern them) but even then, could that CA-universe be "programmed" to make dissappear literally all laws/rules in singularities? Even logical rules?

Comment: I think you need to carefully define what you mean by cellular automata which are continuous in spacetime and/or have continuous values are, and what it means for such things to be computable or otherwise (there's at least one well-defined sense of computability for continuous-values systems, and there may be several).  Just hand-waving about it is not going to get anywhere.

Comment: @tfb As far as I understand if the universe was a continuous CA, it would be fundamentally continuous (it would not be fundamentally discrete). That CA could reproduce at 100% accuracy continuous processes or other things. Also, when talking about singularities (for example, in GR) it is usually said that laws break in there. We cannot predict what happens in the singularity

Comment: @tfb (we can't know whether 1. Literally all laws break, including laws of mathematics and logic, and literally everything can happen in the singularity including inconsistent/illogical/logically impossible things or 2. GR just does not work well there and there is some other version of the theory or another set of laws that govern the singularity). Since we cannot know what happens in the singularity, its evolution it's uncomputable.

Comment: @tfb And even if we could know what happens in them, there is still the case that if #1. happens then inconsistent/illogical/logically impossible things could happen, which are completely uncomputable. Then, since you said that CA-universes could have singularities I was asking: 1. Would they literally have/allow singularities? Could singularities really exist there? Or would it be like in our universe, where singularities are thought to not exist and are avoided/ignored? 2. Could that CA-universe allow singularities to exist even if they are uncomputable?

Comment: @tfb And if yes, could it somehow be able to produce singularities where literally all laws would disappear (including mathematical/logical laws) and thus inconsistent/illogical/logically impossible things could exist in them? We can't predict/know what happens in a singularity, but could a CA-universe be somehow able/programmed to produce a singularity where that would happen? In summary: do you know of any cellular automata-universe model that could allow uncomputable things to exist, like a singularity for example, and thus, actually/really allow truly singularities to exist?

Comment: @tfb (not like in GR or similar models where, whenever a singularity appears, it is avoided/ignored) Even singularities where there would be no laws (even laws of mathematics/logic), producing a "system" in the singularity where even completely inconsistent/illogical/logically impossible things could exist? Is there any CA-universe model where the CA is "programmed" in a way or where computability/uncomputability is defined in a way that uncomputable things would exist in it?

Comment: @tfb (I've read that there are several CA that can reproduce uncomputable things/processes, so maybe there are CA-based-universes models that can produce these singularities, but I need you to confirm. Also, I found a book where the author seems to suggest that there could be CA-based universe models that could be described by a CA not computable by a Turing machine and capable of producing uncomputable things like singularities:

Comment: @tfb https://books.google.es/books?id=xs3fGBGszf8C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22cellular+automata%22+%22universe%22+%22uncomputability%22&source=bl&ots=rLw5hrBep5&sig=EwP0zj7JdzERjFYd-cNL3AhcHvw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw-5GxzunfAhWXAmMBHbwCBw8Q6AEwEHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22cellular%20automata%22%20%22universe%22%20%22uncomputability%22&f=false

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone who thinks that the singularities predicted by GR are real things: they're places where the theory fails and we need a better one.  I would be extraordinarily surprised if cellular automata could do anything uncomputable.